# UnicodeDecodeError when reading from terminal process

Tags: android, python, encoding, utf-8, logcat

I am retrieving [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html) of Android device from command line by using `adb logcat` command. I have no idea of Android device logs encoding (actually trying to find this information for last 3 months) - as there can be many languages in device logs e.g Chinese, Japanese, Arabic or special characters like Emoji or © and more.

My Python3 script looks as follows:

```
import subprocess

ADB_LOCATION = "/Users/F1sherKK/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb"
ADB_DEVCE = "-s emulator-5554"
ADB_LOGCAT = "logcat"

LOGCAT_MONITOR_CMD = "{} {} {}".format(ADB_LOCATION, ADB_DEVCE, ADB_LOGCAT)

with subprocess.Popen(LOGCAT_MONITOR_CMD, shell=True, 
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, 
                      universal_newlines=True, encoding='utf-8') as p:

    for line in p.stdout:
        line_cleaned = line.strip()

        # do something with Logcat line
```

But at some point this line crashes:

```
    for line in p.stdout:
```

With following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position
>   89: invalid start byte

I am not sure anymore where is the error. I think that I am using wrong encoding as I don't know encoding of Android Logcat. Tried various common encodings like `UTF-32`, `UTF-16` or `ASCII` but it always crashes.

How to fix this or at least make partially work - e.g. make it ignore characters it cannot decode?

Comment: For ignoring bytes that cause decoding errors, use `errors='ignore'` in the `Popen` constructor, just as you would in the built-in `open` function.

Comment: I did it before but what I want to do is: to read Logcat line by line (in real time) and save it to dict that is later parsed to .json format with `json.dump(json_dict, output_file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)` function - and if I set `errors='ignore'` in `Popen` then I get errors during file saving.

Comment: What encoding did you use for saving the file? If you use a universal one like UTF-8 or UTF-16, you shouldn't get an encoding error.

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never:

The "problem" is that you have non-decodable bytes in the logcat output. There's nothing wrong from the Python perspective, it's just invalid data.

As far as I can tell, `adb logcat` output should never be non-decodable bytes. If you're seeing bytes that can't be decoded by UTF-8, then your logcat data is probably just corrupt and your best bet is to clear it and try again:

```
$ adb logcat -c
```